# Bank Of Stack Overflow - Borrow reputation points from other users?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

You can borrow money from your friends. Then why not borrow points from anyone to set a bounty ? A bad friend does not return the bounty. To avoid that, we can let users borrow a maximum of 100 points at a time. He cannot borrow more unless he returns the previous loan.

How does this sound ?

Comment: If you *really* want to do this, your friend can award you a bounty on an answer of yours that he likes. That's kind of against the spirit of bounties, but it would work, and I don't think it's actually against the rules. And if you are going to do it just to put it right back into another bounty, it's not even against the spirit of bounties, assuming your friend agrees with the bounty you are placing.

Comment: @BenLee: For that matter, why not just have your friend place the bounty himself?

Comment: off topic comment - its really strange that i get a scholar badge for a question which I too think is bad. :) May be I should get a bad question or unpopular question badge instead :)

Comment: first of all reward is not load its like a bullet , _fire(dont forget to award bounty) and forget_

Comment: Why do you want this?

Comment: @minitech - I don't have enough reputation right now and I might need at least 100 to get more attention for my question. BTW, it looks like you're just 15 and you know a lot of languages ! Did your mum and dad read you Java n PHP code as bedtime stories ? :P

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Why would they do this?  Would it be *just* as a bounty?  If so you could just ask your friend to set the bounty themselves.

I think being allowed to transfer rep is a bad idea.  It gets around the whole point of having reputation.  Reputation is used as a rough measure of

1. How much you know about the topic on hand
2. How much you know about the way the site works

Allowing users to "borrow" or transfer reputation from one person to another defeats the whole purpose of the reputation system.  In order to allow borrowing we would have to redefine "reputation" and in so doing redefine the site.

I'm pretty sure this has been discussed before as well.

If you need two of your accounts to be merged you can request that here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/user-merge

Comment: Reputation may in effect be more of a measure of how much you have *chosen* to contribute ...or how well you can *express* what you know ...or it may even primarily represent how much your *interests* intersect with the interests of people who are voting. But it's still a valuable measure (when taken with a grain of salt); I agree that it should not be *transferred* (except through the bounty system). But the OP here seems to be asking for a feature to create a multi-user bounty, contributed to by multiple users. I'm not sure we need that, but I don't see any major disadvantages of it.

Comment: Well the [FAQ] states:  `Reputation is a rough measurement of how much the community trusts you; it is earned by convincing your peers that you know what you’re talking about.`  So..  Kinda yes, kinda no..  But in general *yes*.

Comment: Yeah, it says that. And that is somewhat true. Trust is more about *how much someone knows*. But think about how reputation is generated--people disproportionately vote (and bounty) questions *and answers* that are *of interest to them.* That's not a problem to be fixed, it's just the way it is. It's been commented on before.

Comment: @EliahKagan, I think the idea of a multi-user bounty actually sounds nice, but I agree that we probably don't really need that -- it would something that happens so rarely and would require enough coding work that it probably doesn't make any sense to implement it.